# Cakephp3 Relative Timezones

Tags: php, cakephp, timezone

In my Cakephp app as a singl point of truth I save the created date of Articles with UTC timezone set as default. When I render dates dates the UTC time is shown which isn't correct. Of course I can set the timezone as follows:

```
$article->created->i18nFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Europe/Paris');
```

However that will only work if all user's were on CET. Is it possible to render the date taking into consideration the user's timezone which of course can be different for any given user?

Comment: Sure, all you have to do is find out the user's timezone, and then use that in your call.

Answer (score 0):

**Considering you maintain user accounts on your database**

- You can create a separate settings page where the user will be able to put or update the timezone.

  `$timezoneList = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);`

This gives all the timezone.

- Use this in the frontend and once the user selects the time zone, store the timezone of the user in the database.
- Use the user's timezone

  `$article->created->i18nFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::FULL, $userTimeZone);`